# Python вылетает с ошибкой при подключении subprocess.popen и во время работы Tkinter.root(). Как исправить?

Tags: python, tkinter, subprocess

Здравствуйте. К сожалению плохо знаком с Python. Реализован элементарный рисовальщик на Tkinter. Сама программа работает с подключением библиотеки Caffe для распознавания рукописных цифр. 
По нажатию кнопки Recognize должен произойти вызов subprocess.popen() команды

python /Users/DiKey/caffe-master/python/classify.py --print_results --model_def /Users/DiKey/caffe-master/examples/mnist/lenet.prototxt --pretrained_model /Users/DiKey/caffe-master/examples/mnist/lenet_iter_60000.caffemodel --force_grayscale --center_only --labels_file /Users/DiKey/caffe-master/data/mnist/mnist_words.txt --images_dim 28,28 /Users/DiKey/Documents/Xcode/NeuralNetwork/Digit.png results file

от туда хочется получить последнюю строку(из данных выведенных в консоли после запуска команды)
и распечатать эту строку в Label  Ткинтера.

На деле при нажатии на кнопку вылетает ошибка Python неожиданно завершил работу. Проверки показали, что root = Tk() и вызов subprocess.popen дают эту ошибку. То есть я могу либо открыть графический интерфейс и работать в нем, но не использовать subprocess.popen , либо я могу использовать subprocess.popen, но тогда я должен закомментить вызов root= Tk()

В чем проблема? Что я делаю не так?

КОД :

```
import sys
import os
import subprocess
from subprocess import *
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image,ImageDraw
import tkFileDialog
import cv2
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams['backend'] = "Qt4Agg"
import numpy
import lmdb

#white = (255,255,255)

class Paint(Frame):
 def __init__(self, parent):
    Frame.__init__(self, parent)

    self.parent = parent
    self.color = "white"
    self.configure(background='grey')
    self.brush_size = 15
    self.setUI()

def Clear_all(self):
    self.canv.delete("all")
    del self.cv_pil
    del self.img_pil
    self.img_pil = Image.new("L", (222, 223), 0)
    self.cv_pil = ImageDraw.Draw(self.img_pil)

def Save(self):
    filename = "/Users/DiKey/Documents/Xcode/NeuralNetwork/Digit.png"
    self.img_pil.save(filename)

def set_brush_size(self, new_size):
    self.brush_size = new_size

def set_label_digit(self):
    filename = "/Users/DiKey/Documents/Xcode/NeuralNetwork/Digit.png"
    self.img_pil.save(filename)
    v = StringVar()
    digit=Label(self, textvariable=v,font=("Helvetica", 95))
    digit.grid(row=3,column=3)
    p = subprocess.Popen(["python /Users/DiKey/caffe-master/python/classify.py --print_results --model_def /Users/DiKey/caffe-master/examples/mnist/lenet.prototxt --pretrained_model /Users/DiKey/caffe-master/examples/mnist/lenet_iter_60000.caffemodel --force_grayscale --center_only --labels_file /Users/DiKey/caffe-master/data/mnist/mnist_words.txt --images_dim 28,28 /Users/DiKey/Documents/Xcode/NeuralNetwork/Digit.png resultsfile"], shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    p.wait()    # дождаться выполнения
    result = p.communicate()[0]
    v.set(result)

def draw(self, event):
    self.canv.create_oval(event.x - self.brush_size,event.y - self.brush_size,event.x + self.brush_size,event.y + self.brush_size,fill=self.color, outline=self.color)
    self.cv_pil.ellipse((event.x - self.brush_size,event.y - self.brush_size,event.x + self.brush_size,event.y + self.brush_size),fill=self.color, outline=self.color)

def setUI(self):

    self.parent.title("Digits Recognition")
    self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

    self.columnconfigure(6, weight=1)
    self.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)

    self.canv = Canvas(self,width=222,height=223, bg="black")
    self.canv.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=7,
                   padx=5, pady=5)
    self.img_pil = Image.new("L", (222, 223), 0)
    self.cv_pil = ImageDraw.Draw(self.img_pil)
    #black = (0, 0, 0)
    # img_pil = Image.new("RGB", (222, 223), black)
    #cv_pil = ImageDraw.Draw(img_pil)

    self.canv.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.draw)

    color_lab = Label(self, text="CLEAR: ")
    color_lab.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=6)

    clear_btn = Button(self, text="Clear all", width=10,
                                      command=lambda: self.Clear_all())
    clear_btn.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)

    save = Button(self, text="Save", width=10,
                      command=lambda: self.Save())
    save.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=W)

    recognize_btn = Button(self, text="RECOGNIZE", width=20,
                  command=lambda: self.set_label_digit())
    recognize_btn.grid(row=3, column=2)
    #digit= Label(self, text="",font=("Helvetica", 45));
    #digit.grid(row=3,column=3)



def main():
  root = Tk()
  root.geometry("600x600+300+300")
  app = Paint(root)
  root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: Добавьте вывод ошибки.

Comment: каким образом? консоль не открывается даже. сразу выскакивает окно Python неожиданно завершил работу  и можно отправить отчет либо нажать ок

Comment: А свой главный код, откуда вызывается "падающая" функция, из консоли запускаете?

Comment: весь код, что в вопросе это и есть код который я запускаю. запускаю все в Xcode. соответственно после запуска у меня открывается окно Tkinter с холстом, где я рисую цифру и кнопками : Сохранить картинку, Очистить холст, РАСПОЗНАТЬ. вот кнопка распознать должна с помощью subprocess.popen открыть консоль с запущенной в ней командой python....(описана в коде) и после выполнения этой команды хочу получить последнюю строку из выведенного в консоль. Но на деле после после клика по РАСПОЗНАТЬ - вместо открытия консоли сразу выпадает ошибка PYTHON неожиданно завершил работу

Comment: @DanKamilov 1- приведите полный traceback. Если не знаете как открыть терминал и запустить в нём ваш питон-скрипт, то задайте отдельный вопрос. 2- Не нужно весь код, который у вас есть приводить. [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

```
def setpatch_execute(self, file: str):
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        for line in f.read().split('\n'):
            if line.startswith('@@'):
                sql_file = os.path.join(os.path.split(file)[0], line[2:])
                self.execute_file(sql_file)

    ins_int_vers_res = self.sqlplus_execute_cmd(self.last__ver)[0].decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
    return ins_int_vers_res


def execute_file(self, file: str, err_str='ORA-', echo=1):
    std_out, std_err = self.sqlplus_execute_file(file)

    out, err = std_out.decode('utf-8', 'ignore'), std_err.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
    if err:
        self.global_.STATE.error(err)

    if err_str in out:
        for line in out.split('\n'):
            if err_str in line:
                self.global_.STATE.error(line)
    elif echo:
        self.global_.STATE.debug(out)

    out = '\n'.join([o for o in out.split('\n', 5) if o][:-4]).replace('\r', '')
    return out


def _sqlplus(self):
    return Popen(['sqlplus', '-S', self.__auth], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)


def sqlplus_execute_file(self, file: str):
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        return self.sqlplus_execute_cmd(f.read())


def sqlplus_execute_cmd(self, cmd: str):
    db = self._sqlplus()
    db.stdin.write(cmd.encode('utf-8', 'ignore'))
    db.stdin.close()
    return db.communicate()
```